# Can I set a final variable in Java with a result of a divison?

Tags: java, static, singleton, final

I want to have a global-scale variable, so some graphical objects can always have the same size in relation to the window. My idea:

```
public static final double GLOBALSCALE = SCREENWIDTH / 1920;
```

But my variable is zero at that point.
It happens in the datafield of a Singleton-Patterned-Class.. did I understand anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake by dividing an int to an int and expect a double as it's outcome. You need to devide by a double:

```
public static final double GLOBALSCALE = SCREENWIDTH / 1920.0;
```

Notice the difference, `1920.0` is a double while `1920` is an int. If one of the two is a double java will not do integer division but double instead.

Or cast the division to a double like so:

```
public static final double GLOBALSCALE = SCREENWIDTH / (double)1920;
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that works! Dammit, thats really a noob-mistake!